# How to open PDF file with Org-ref?

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

I have been trying to use the `org-ref` package with emacs and I copied the setup presented in the package where I placed the `.bib` files in a directory called `~/papers/` along with any pdfs of the papers in the same folder:

```
(use-package ivy-bibtex
    :straight t
    :init
    (setq bibtex-completion-bibliography '("~/papers/phd_ref.bib"
                                           "~/papers/masc_ref.bib")
          bibtex-completion-library-path '("~/papers/")
          bibtex-completion-notes-path "~/papers/"
          bibtex-completion-notes-template-multiple-files "* ${author-or-editor}, ${title}, ${journal}, (${year}) :${=type=}: \n\nSee [[cite:&${=key=}]]\n"

          bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields '(keywords)
          bibtex-completion-display-formats
          '((article       . "${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${year:4} ${author:36} ${title:*} ${journal:40}")
            (inbook        . "${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${year:4} ${author:36} ${title:*} Chapter ${chapter:32}")
            (incollection  . "${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${year:4} ${author:36} ${title:*} ${booktitle:40}")
            (inproceedings . "${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${year:4} ${author:36} ${title:*} ${booktitle:40}")
            (t             . "${=has-pdf=:1}${=has-note=:1} ${year:4} ${author:36} ${title:*}"))
          bibtex-completion-pdf-open-function
          (lambda (fpath)
            (call-process "open" nil 0 nil fpath))))

(use-package org-ref
    :straight t
    :init
    (setq bibtex-autokey-year-length 4
          bibtex-autokey-name-year-separator "-"
          bibtex-autokey-year-title-separator "-"
          bibtex-autokey-titleword-separator "-"
          bibtex-autokey-titlewords 2
          bibtex-autokey-titlewords-stretch 1
          bibtex-autokey-titleword-length 5)
)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c ]") org-ref-insert-cite-function)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") org-ref-insert-ref-function)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c l") org-ref-insert-label-function)
```

I am able to insert the citation using `C-c ]` and when I click on the citation, I can press p to open its pdf which I have also downloaded and kept in the same `~/papers/` folder. But when I press `p` , it does not open the pdf file and simply states Searching for program: No such file or directory, open. My goal was to click on the citation link and have org-noter open it up so I can start taking notes on the paper. So how can I configure `org-ref` to properly open up the pdf file?

Here is the error I receive:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "open")
  call-process("open" nil 0 nil "/home/user/papers/huang91_optic_coher_tomog.pdf")
  (lambda (fpath) (call-process "open" nil 0 nil fpath))("/home/user/papers/huang91_optic_coher_tomog.pdf")
  org-ref-open-pdf-at-point()
  funcall-interactively(org-ref-open-pdf-at-point)
  call-interactively(org-ref-open-pdf-at-point)
  hydra--call-interactively-remap-maybe(org-ref-open-pdf-at-point)
  org-ref-citation-hydra/org-ref-open-pdf-at-point-and-exit()
  funcall-interactively(org-ref-citation-hydra/org-ref-open-pdf-at-point-and-exit)
  call-interactively(org-ref-citation-hydra/org-ref-open-pdf-at-point-and-exit nil nil)
  command-execute(org-ref-citation-hydra/org-ref-open-pdf-at-point-and-exit)
```

Comment: Try doing `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and redoing the `p`. You should get a backtrace which you should add to your question. That will give much more information about what is going on and limit the number of wrong turns that we might make.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the error message

Comment: It's better to add text than a screenshot (also easier for you to edit your user name out, rather than firing up an image editor - and easier for me to cut-and-paste from). What happens when you say `open /path/to/some/file.pdf` on the command line? Is this on a MacOSX system?

Comment: BTW, it's complaining about the command `open`, not about the PDF file.

Comment: This is running on windows wsl2

Comment: I get a similar error when I type ```open /path/to/some/file.pdf``` in ```eval-expression```

Comment: The trick is to try it *outside* of emacs, on a command prompt somewhere. Is there a bash shell in WSL2? If it does not work there, then emacs and org-ref are off the hook. When it works there, then it will work in emacs/org-ref as well. But I know almost nothing about Windows and nothing about WSL2, so I hope somebody else comes to the rescue.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with evince. I guess there is no command called ```open``` in ubuntu and ```xdg-open``` works but it shuts down the pdf right away so ```evince``` was the only one that worked.

Comment: Was this the value of `bibtex-completion-pdf-open-function`? In my emacs, that is actually set to `find-file`. That opens the PDF in Emacs (with either `docview` or `pdf-tools` if you have it installed), which you might (or might not) prefer.

Comment: yes that was the issue. I suppose I can play around with the different commands for opening pdfs in emacs to see which one I like. Or better yet, opening it automatically in org noter.